# Using Apache Hive feature masking and filtering of rows/columns

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, apache-hive

Recently I've found out that  masking and filtering of rows/columns feature was added in Hive. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13125 But still there is no documentation about it. During my research I've found out that we can use this feature through Apache Ranger. Is it possible to configure and use this feature manually using hive cli or beeline?

Comment: You can use *voluntarily* the masking functions in a query, or in a view. But to *force* the use of the masking functions to specific users, automatically, based on access privileges... then you need a security plug-in such as Ranger. And the plug-in will have to rewrite the queries dynamically.

Comment: BTW these masking functions are listed in the documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DataMaskingFunctions

Comment: Thanks for answering.